# How would I create a "Choose your Own Adventure game" on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, branch

New to coding, and I decided to create an interactive, onclick adventure game using 6 images I pulled from online.

I added the the first image to canvas and put a cool little animation in front of the image on canvas, but now I'm left with a big problem.

This whole game is done on ONE canvas, with MULTIPLE, as well as BRANCHING on click events.

Example: On the title screen, the user can either select "Start Game", or "Credits" (done as clickable text).

If the user selects "Start Game", the screen transitions to picture number 2, after clicking again, picture number 2 blurs out and narration text will appear in front of the user. However, if they select "Credits", the screen transitions instead to a different picture, picture number 3. On picture number 3, the credits display in an slow automatic scrolling up fashion.

I've looked this up online, but I usually get answers in a general ballpark of what I'm looking for, some results I've found are switch cases(not much experience with them, let alone make a BRANCHING switch case), the Undum framework for interactive story telling, event handlers, etc.

I haven't worked much with Javascript or with canvas, and before I tackled this project, I thought it best to present my project question outright and get a experienced opinion on it, as well as break the project down piece by piece and form some kind of method of attack.

Knowing how this project is going to work, what resources or coding methods would you guys recommend for me to use? What would this "branching" animation tree even look like?

Here is what my code is so far:

**-- HTML --**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Detective</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!--   load in the jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**-- CSS --**

```
body{
  background:#000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

canvas{
/*the code below this activates the canvas border, turn it on to visibly see how big the canvas is */

/*  border: 1px solid red;*/  

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;
    display: none;
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Betty Noir Regular';
  src: url('/assets/bettynoir.ttf');
}
```

**-- JS --**

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
var w = canvas.width = 800,
    h = canvas.height = 400;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://oi41.tinypic.com/4i2aso.jpg';

var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://i2.wp.com/i2.listal.com/image/2669447/500full.jpg";



var position = {x : 410, y : 238};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var particles = [];
var random = function(min, max){
  return Math.random()*(max-min)*min;
};

function Particle(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velY = -2;
  this.velX = (random(1, 10)-5)/10;
  this.size = random(3, 5)/10;
  this.alpha = 1;
  this.update = function(){
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.velY *= 0.99;
    if(this.alpha < 0){this.alpha = 0;}
    c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.x, this.y);
    c.scale(this.size, this.size);
    c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    c.restore();
    this.alpha *= 0.96;
    this.size += 0.02;//  
  };
}

var draw = function(){
  var p = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
  particles.push(p);

  // draw the background image before you draw the particles
  c.drawImage(background,160,0);
  c.font="20px Betty Noir Regular";
  c.fillStyle = "white";
  c.fillText("Start",500,200);

  c.font="20px Betty Noir Regular";
  c.fillStyle = "white";
  c.fillText("Credits",500,250);

  while(particles.length > 500) particles.shift();

  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
  {
    particles[i].update();
  }
};



setInterval(draw, 3500/60);


$(document).ready(function() {
 $("canvas").fadeIn(7000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#noir-song").get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.

I would say get rid of `setInterval` as it will only cause you problems in the long run. As you have a particle system, some devices may not handle the load that well and as `setInterval` does not check to see if the last render job is done befor it puts a call on the call stack you could end up overflowing the call stack and crashing the app.

Use `window.requestAnimationFrame(functionName)`

As follows

```
// your main render function
function draw(){
    // do your stuff
    requestAnimationFrame(draw); // needs to be call for every new frame
}
draw(); // start it all happening.
```

`requestAnimationFrame` is sensitive to rendering load, will try its best to maintain an even frame rate 1/60th or 60fps. Syncs with monitor refresh rates if possible so you don't get shearing. It is designed for animations (hence the name) so give it a try.

I would ask "why use jquery?" you will be using browsers that support canvas and jquery offers no real benefit but that of legacy browser support, and only adds to the complexity of the pages and increases the load time. You only use it for page ready, so seems a bit of a waste. Remove jQuery and use onload to replace the ready calls

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   // your startup up code
});
```

A better way of creating particles. Using new is slow especially when you are creating many instances of the same thing.

Try

```
// define the function to update once. In the new Particle() version
// javascript actually has to create this function every time you create a particle.
// This makes it quicker.
var particleUpdate = function(){
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.velY *= 0.99;
    // a quicker way to clamp a value
    // if(this.alpha < 0){this.alpha = 0;} // done in the following line
    c.globalAlpha = Math.max(0,this.alpha); // returns the max value so while 
                                            // alpha > 0 it returns alpha
                                            // when alpha < 0 returns max 
                                            // which is 0;
    //c.save();  // dont need this here do it outside the loop that renders
                 // the particles. Save and restore are expensive in  terms
                 // of GPU performance and should be avoided if possible. 
    // the translate and scale can be done in one call halving the time
    // to do the same thing
    //c.translate(this.x, this.y);
    //c.scale(this.size, this.size);
    // use setTransform does the same as translate and scale but in one step
    c.setTransform(this.size,0,0,this.size,this.x,this.y)
    c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    // c.restore(); see above
    this.alpha *= 0.96;
    this.size += 0.02;//  
};
var createParticle = function(x,y){
    return {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        velY:-2,
        velX:(random(1, 10)-5)/10,
        size:random(3, 5)/10,
        alpha = 1,
        update:particleUpdate,
    }
}
```

Then to create

particles.push(createParticle(position.x, position.y));

Update and cull as you are already doing just add the save and restore outside the loop. Also getting "particles.length" is slower than a direct variable. So rewrite the loop as follows

```
  var len = particles.length
  c.save()
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
       particles[i].update();
  }
  c.restore();
```

It will not make much difference in this case as there is not that much going on. But as you push for more and more fx, more bang per frame performance will become a major problem. Learning efficient methods early on will help.